# Support for ',' in input type="number" in IE 11 using Angular + material

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I need to accept 10,12 as a valid number in IE 11 because the users only have a German number pad as an input device which only has a comma as a decimal separator.

The current behavior is (userinput -> value used)

```
10,12 -> 10
```

The desired behavior is

```
10,12 -> 10.12
10.12 -> 10.12
```

As it is currently in Chrome.

My current idea is to implement a ControlValueAccessor for an input type="text" which parses the value into a number, but my attempts for that failed.

The input has to work with reactiveForms and has to be a numeric value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and was not able to get a comma as the decimal separator with `<input type="number">` even when setting the language to a different locale and using a step smaller than 1:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" lang="en-US">
```

> So I opted for a custom solution based on `<input type="text">` with a custom filtering  mechanism to only allow numbers in.
>
> See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-custom-input-number) for a complete demo.

The most important part is filtering what the user inputs in the field. I suggest you write a directive that listens to input/keydown/paste events and that uses a regex to only allow float/integer numbers.

The following regex (`/^-?\d*(,|\.)?\d*$/`) allows a number to begin with an optional `-` followed by digits, then a comma or dot and more digits.

If the new value (current value + key pressed) does not match the regex, simply prevent the event from happening with `event.preventDefault()`. Otherwise, do nothing and let the value go to the input.

Note that you also have to take care of the copy/cut/paste/undo/redo special keys. And also take into account the cursor position and the selection if any.

Once the filtering is done, you can implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface and bind it to your input via its `change/input` events. Do the string to number conversions in these handlers and do the number to string conversion in a getter or a pipe that you bind to the `value` attribute.

Here is an example of such a directive, you could generalize it by giving the regex as an input parameter.

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNumberOnly]'
})
export class NumberOnlyDirective {
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  public onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const { key } = event;
    if (this.isSpecialOperation(event) || !this.isKeyPrintable(event)) {
      return;
    }
    const newValue = this.getNewValue(event.target as HTMLInputElement, key);
    if (!this.valueIsValid(newValue)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  public onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent): void {
    const pastedText = event.clipboardData.getData('text');
    const newValue = this.getNewValue(event.target as HTMLInputElement, pastedText);
    if (!this.valueIsValid(newValue)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  private getNewValue(target: HTMLInputElement, str: string): string {
    const { value = '', selectionStart, selectionEnd } = target;
    return [
        ...value.split('').splice(0, selectionStart),
        str,
        ...value.split('').splice(selectionEnd)].join('');
  }

  private valueIsValid(value: string): boolean {
    return /^-?\d*(,|\.)?\d*$/.test(value);
  }

  private isSpecialOperation(event: KeyboardEvent): boolean {
    const { keyCode, ctrlKey, metaKey } = event;
    // allow ctr-A/C/V/X/Y/Z
    const keysACVXYZ = [65, 67, 86, 88, 89, 90];
    if ((ctrlKey || metaKey) && keysACVXYZ.indexOf(keyCode) >= 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  private isKeyPrintable(event: KeyboardEvent): boolean {
    const { keyCode } = event;
    return (
      (keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58)      || // number keys
      keyCode === 32 || keyCode === 13    || // spacebar & return key(s)
      (keyCode > 64 && keyCode < 91)      || // letter keys
      (keyCode > 95 && keyCode < 112)     || // numpad keys
      (keyCode > 185 && keyCode < 193)    || // ;=,-./` (in order)
      (keyCode > 218 && keyCode < 223));      // [\]' (in order)
  }
}
```

And a custom input-number component implementing `ControlValueAccessor`:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, forwardRef, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-number',
  template: `
    <input
      type="text"
      #input
      appNumberOnly
      [placeholder]="placeholder"
      [value]="_stringifiedValue"
      (input)="_onInput($event.target.value)"
      (change)="_onChange($event.target.value)"
      (blur)="input.value = _stringifiedValue">
  `,
  styles: [`
    :host { width: 100%; display: block; }
    input { width: 100%; }
  `],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputNumberComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class InputNumberComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  private onChange = [(_: number) => {}];
  private onTouch = [() => {}];

  @Input() placeholder;

  @ViewChild('input') _input: ElementRef;

  @Input()
  get value(): number {
    return this._value;
  }
  set value(value: number) {
    const safeValue = this.safeValue(value);
    if (safeValue !== this._value) {
      this._value = safeValue;
      this.onChange.forEach(fn => fn(safeValue));
    }
  }
  private _value: number = undefined;

  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  get _stringifiedValue(): string {
    const val = (this._input.nativeElement.value || '').replace('.', ',');
    if (val === '-' || val === ',') return val;
    const safeValue = this.safeValue(this.value);
    return this.stringify(safeValue).replace('.', ',');
  }

  _onInput(value: string): void {
    this.value = this.safeValue(value);
  }

  _onChange(value: string): void {
    this.value = this.safeValue(value);
    this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
  }

  private safeValue(val: string | number): number {
    const safeValue = parseFloat(this.stringify(val).replace(',', '.'));
    return isNaN(safeValue) ? undefined : safeValue;
  }

  private stringify(val: string | number): string {
    return val === undefined || val === null ? '' : `${val}`;
  }

  public registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange.push(fn);
  }

  public registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouch.push(fn);
  }

  public writeValue(inputValue: number): void {
    this.value = this.safeValue(inputValue);
  }
}
```

The component can then be used with two-way binding with `[(ngModel)]` or with `[(value)]`. It will work with reactive-forms too:

```
<app-input-number [(ngModel)]="value"></app-input-number>
<app-input-number [(value)]="value"></app-input-number>
```

Comment: the following template throws an error:
`<mat-form-field><app-input-number formControlName="numericValue" placeholder="numericValue" ></gs-input-number></mat-form-field>` 
Error _italic_Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl._italic_

Comment: your example works great but breaks when i put it in a mat form field

Comment: Oh I see, could you try to add matInput on the app-input-number component ?

Comment: yes, i tried to add it on the component and in the component

Comment: OK, it works by adding matFormField in the app input number component

Comment: in IE the ',' on the numpad has the key 'Decimal' so i added` if (stri === 'Decimal') {
      str = ',';
    } else {
      str = stri;
    }` in getNewValue and `if (event.key === ',' || event.key === 'Decimal') {
      return true;
    }` in isKeyPrintable

Comment: @Ivan Tarskich, thanks for the information! I will test this as soon as I get on a computer with IE